# Jest-Expo ( SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' )

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, expo

can someone help me trough this please, dont get why i get this export error? [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr2VF.png)

[My test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzPRQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions to set up per https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/ ?

This section looks most promising based on reading our error: https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/#jest-configuration